# What does mean type="class" in decision tree algorithm

Tags: r, decision-tree

I have a model in decision tree that works fine.

```
predArbreDecision=predict(ad.apprentissage,newdata=test,type="class")
```

I'm asking now, what does it mean type="class".

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: I have searched on google but I didn't found any response.

Comment: Did you check the R documentation though?

Comment: It means the `Y` variable is factor variable. The algorithm predicts the `class` of the `Y` variable. For ex : `High, Medium,Low`. This is not  a regression tree it is the classification tree. Thanks!